# Replace a file, if existing, or else create a new file, using NIO.2 in Java 7+

Tags: java, file, nio, nio2

The [`Files.write`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#write(java.nio.file.Path,byte%5B%5D,java.nio.file.OpenOption...)) & [`Files.writeString`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#writeString(java.nio.file.Path,java.lang.CharSequence,java.nio.charset.Charset,java.nio.file.OpenOption...)) methods in Java 7+ are a concise handy way to write text to a file.

```java
try
{
    Files.write (
            Paths.get ( "/Users/My_UserName/Example.txt" ) ,
            List.of( "Hello world" , Instant.now().toString() ) ,
            StandardCharsets.UTF_8 ,
            StandardOpenOption.WRITE ;
}
catch ( IOException e )
{
    throw new RuntimeException ( e );
}
```

Unfortunately, I cannot get this to work the first time, before the file exists. I get an exception thrown:

> `java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException`

My goal is always blow away any existing file, to write a new fresh file.

I tried adding `TRUNCATE_EXISTING`.

```java
try
{
    Files.write (
            Paths.get ( "/Users/My_UserName/Example.txt" ) ,
            List.of( "Hello world" , Instant.now().toString() ) ,
            StandardCharsets.UTF_8 ,
            StandardOpenOption.WRITE,
            StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING );  // <--- Combining Open-options.
}
catch ( IOException e )
{
    throw new RuntimeException ( e );
}
```

But that too fails when the file does not already exist.

Is there some combination of [`OpenOption`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/OpenOption.html)/[`StandardOpenOption`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/StandardOpenOption.html) objects to make use of these convenient `Files` methods?

Comment: `TRUNCATE_EXISTING, CREATE` *together* seem to do it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### `CREATE`, `WRITE`, & `TRUNCATE_EXISTING`

So the behaviour you want is the effect of using CREATE, and TRUNCATE_EXISTING options with WRITE.

```java
    Files.write (
            Paths.get ( "/Users/My_UserName/Example.txt" ) ,
            List.of ( "Hello world" , Instant.now ( ).toString ( ) ) ,
            StandardCharsets.UTF_8 ,
            StandardOpenOption.CREATE ,
            StandardOpenOption.WRITE ,
            StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING
    );
```

Fortunately, this is the default behaviour, as documented by both your API references like [Files.write](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#write(java.nio.file.Path,byte%5B%5D,java.nio.file.OpenOption...)) :

> If no options are present then this method works as if the CREATE,
> TRUNCATE_EXISTING, and WRITE options are present.

So simply don’t override that default - don’t give that WRITE, so

```java
    Files.write (
            Paths.get ( "/Users/My_UserName/Example.txt" ) ,
            List.of ( "Hello world" , Instant.now ( ).toString ( ) ) ,
            StandardCharsets.UTF_8  
            // <--- Omitting the 3 CREATE, WRITE, & TRUNCATE_EXISTING arguments.
    );
```

Also, the `Charset` parameter is [documented as optional](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#write(java.nio.file.Path,java.lang.Iterable,java.nio.file.OpenOption...)), defaulting to [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), in Java 8+ (but not the original [Java 7 arrival of this class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html)). So we can further shorten your code to this:

```java
    Files.write (
            Paths.get ( "/Users/My_UserName/Example.txt" ) ,
            List.of ( "Hello world" , Instant.now ( ).toString ( ) ) 
            // <--- Omitting the StandardCharsets.UTF_8  argument.
            // <--- Omitting the 3 CREATE, WRITE, & TRUNCATE_EXISTING arguments.
    );
```

Comment: I'm pretty certain that from 17, the default *would* be UTF-8, so yes, that might be a redundant parameter too. OTOH, it might give some (particularly Windows) users a  problem if they *don't* specify an 8-bit encoding

Comment: Indeed.  Some newer I/O routines default to UTF-8, some default to the platform default charset, and up to Java 17 inclusive, that's a bit of a crapshoot.  I work on a lot of legacy code, don't have a clear mental model for which category (UTF-8/platform default) of routines any given method falls into, so I have a bad habit of writing StandardCharsets.UTF_8 regardless.

Comment: @ArfurNarf For `Files.*` specifically, `UTF-8` has _always_ been the default. From Java18 or whatnot, it's the default everywhere, but Files has always defaulted to that.

Comment: Thanks. We have a lot of java.io of the form `out = new ThisWriter(new ThatStream(new FileThing)))`. One day I'll get annoyed enough to blitz it all. I only recently decided I couldn't stand seeing "UTF-8" as a string, replacing it by StandardCharsets.UTF_8 (with the intent of getting rid of the never-going-to-happen exception handling).

Comment: @g00se - [JEP 400](https://openjdk.org/jeps/400), in Java 18

Comment: (A) I found the last of the `write` methods does indeed document that `Charset` is optional, defaulting to UTF-8, going back to Java 8 (not the original Java 7 arrival of this class). So I replaced your last paragraph. (B) Thanks so much for your Answer. My mind was not processing the writing in the Javadoc, but your Answer makes it all clear now.